# (Bootstrap/JQuery) How to select each .'col-md-4' element within '.row' parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make each row element react when hovered (using Animate.css). What I am unsure about is how to get JQuery to treat each element separately when hovered. Do I need to somehow loop through the child elements? Or is there an easier way? Any help in the right direction is much appreciated! Thanks you all

Eric

```js
$('.row.writing').children().hover(function(){

 $(this).addClass('animated fadeInLeft')
});
```

```html
<div class="row writing">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 b"><a href="writing/wearcomp.pdf"><img   src="images/pencil113.png"/></a><br/>On Wearable Computing</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 b"><a href="writing/wearcomp.pdf"><img src="images/pencil113.png"/></a><br/>Early State Based Civilizations: Aztec vs Maya</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 b"><a href="writing/wearcomp.pdf"><img src="images/pencil113.png"/></a><br/>Cloud Computing & mobile device security</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 b"><a href="writing/wearcomp.pdf"><img src="images/pencil113.png"/></a><br/>Looking Beneath the Screen: The Changing Nature of Interpersonal Communications</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 b"><a href="writing/wearcomp.pdf"><img src="images/pencil113.png"/></a><br/>Out-of-Africa vs Multiregional: Comparing models of Human origins</div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

-->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('.row.writing > div').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInLeft')
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hk76cddo/)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @EricFurspan Nice to here. If this answer helps you, then can vote and accept as answer.

Comment: Im trying to make it so the code initiates the animation effect each time the user hovers, rather than just firing one time. Any ideas? I tried to removeClass but that seems to break the whole thing. any ideas? And Im new to stackoverflow so they dont let me upvote publicly yet :/

Comment: Got it. All I had to do was change 'addClass' to 'toggleClass'

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors for this purpose. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ofu0rn4y/) is example.

```
.row.writing > .col-xs-6:hover {
    background: red;
}
```